# Is it possible to configure the date widget in CommCare to use DD/MM/YYYY instead of MM/DD/YYYY?

Tags: commcare

If your form has a date question (where the user scrolls through a calendar type widget to select a date), this shows up as MM/DD/YYYY.  Is there any way to make that use the DD/MM/YYYY format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordering of the date fields (day, month, year) is actually determined by the default language settings on your phone.  To get the dates to appear as MM/DD/YYYY, go to the Android Settings -> Language & Input and set the Language to "English (United States)". To get the dates to appear as DD/MM/YYYY, go to the Android Settings -> Language & Input and set the Language to "English (United Kingdom)".  For languages other than English, you may need to try out different regional language settings to find the right choice.

Comment: English (UK) works as I'd hope, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking through various Javarosa implementations (like CommCare, ODK) it appears changes in the Date or DateTime entry format needs to be done via specific widgets tied to the required format (e.g. the Nepali formatted picker in Commcare via the "appearance" attribute in form builder)
So it looks like that's a "no."